# need to sort .txt file into data frame with Pandas using Python 2.7

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, reorganize

I'm new to using programming languages and I'm having trouble working this particular issue out. I'm a journalist trying to use Python to reorganize 911 data from a county dispatch office that has been provided in a .txt file.
This is how one call comes in the current format:

```
Incident Number: PD160010001
Incident Type: SUSPICIOUS PERSON(S)          
EMS Blk: 186605  Fire Blk: 65005   Police Blk: 22145 
Location: Location name,22                  
          at XXXX Name RD ,22                
       Entered: 01/01/16  00:00
    Dispatched: 01/01/16  00:00
       Enroute: 01/01/16  00:00
      On Scene: 01/01/16  00:00
     Transport:   /  /      :  
Trans Complete:   /  /      :  
        Closed: 01/01/16  00:04

01/01/16  00:00  OUTSRV
01/01/16  00:00  DISPOS  22H4  
01/01/16  00:00  PREMPT  22H4  
01/01/16  00:00  DISPOS  2212  
01/01/16  00:00  EXCH    22H4  
01/01/16  00:01  ADDER   22H4  
01/01/16  00:04  CLEAR   2212  
01/01/16  00:04  CLEAR   22H4  
01/01/16  00:04  CLOSE   22H4
```

I was able to reorganize this in Excel using the Right and Left functions and a few other steps to get something like this:

```
Incident Number Incident Type         EMS Blk:    Closed
PD160010001     SUSPICIOUS PERSON(S)  186605  ... 01/01/16  00:04
```

The 9-10 rows of data with dispatched times at the bottom of each incident is redundant is not necessary.

What I'm having trouble with is finding a way to tell Pandas to take the name to the left of the colon and recognize that as one column head, while taking the info to the right of the column and assign it to the corresponding column, then repeat until after the closed column and skip the redundant information.

One year's worth of data in the .txt file is approximately 6 million rows and is cut down to just over 501,000 once it's been reorganized. Doing it in excel by hand is going to take about 4 hours per file and I want to do an analysis of call times over 10 years.

I need to learn to do this in Python to make it a practical project to follow through with. 
Thank everyone. First time posting a question here.

Comment: I was not careful in my formatting of that spreadsheet form. Incident Number, Incident Type and so on are the column headers and anything to the right of the colons for those names is the corresponding data in the next row.

Comment: Is that the entire file? i.e. is it one call per file ?

Comment: No, that is just one call in the file. I thought it would be to bulky to bring in more than one call, but each call is set up the same. So I guess I need to know how to sort out the one call and repeat it roughly 500,000 times in the file.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing how to separate rows.

Comment: When I used the pd.read_table function in pandas, it printed out a much neater form of the file. I have to step away for a bit but I'll try and add multiple calls in that setup when i get back.

Comment: Okay, so apparently I'm so new it this that I don't know how to properly post the formatted table. but here it goes: 
 Incident Number: PD160010001
0 Incident Type: SUSPICIOUS PERSON(S)
1 EMS Blk: 186605 Fire Blk: 65005 Police Blk:...
2 Location: ROSEDALE CEMETARY ,22
3 at 3850 RICHLIEU RD ,22
4 Entered: 01/01/16 00:00
5 Dispatched: 01/01/16 00:00
6 Enroute: 01/01/16 00:00
7 On Scene: 01/01/16 00:00
8 Transport: / / :
9 Trans Complete: / / :
10 Closed: 01/01/16 00:04

... each line from the original is a new row basically

Comment: Highlight the code and use ctrl+k, that adds 4 spaces before each code line. You can't format in the comment, you have to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the layout of the data is ambiguous, so I'm making some assumptions. I'm guessing the .txt file looks somewhat like this:

```
          header2  header3  header4  header5  header6  header7  header8  header9
index 1   data12   data13   data14   data15   data16   data17   data18   data19
index 2   data22   data23   data24   data25   data26   data27   data28   data29
```

Where each index corresponds to a certain call and each column corresponds to some attribute of the call with the headers denoting what the data in the column represents.

The following program turns the above .txt file into a pandas dataframe and prints it out.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

with open(filename) as file:
    rows = file.readlines()
columns = rows[0] # get the top row
columns = re.sub(' {2,}', ',', columns) # substitute whitespaces of more than
                                     # two spaces with commas
columns = columns.strip().split(',') # turn the row into a list
content = rows[1:] # All but the first row
content = [re.sub(' {2,}',',',row).strip() for row in content] # again, whitespace to commas
content = [row.split(',') for row in content] # turn rows into lists
index = [row[0] for row in content] # take the first element of each row as the index
content = [row[1:] for row in content] # remove index from content
df = pd.DataFrame(data=content, index=index, columns=columns) # Combine into a dataframe
print(df)
```

Here we've assumed the columns have at least two spaces between them and that your data won't have any double spaces in it. If there's more space than that between the columns, you can change the regex to look for 3 or more consecutive spaces.

The output is

```
        header2 header3 header4 header5 header6 header7 header8 header9
index 1  data12  data13  data14  data15  data16  data17  data18  data19
index 2  data22  data23  data24  data25  data26  data27  data28  data29
```

but you could do much more than print it out now that it's a dataframe.

Comment: This is how it prints with pd.read_table (too long to fit one in comment totally)
 Incident Number: PD160010001
0 Incident Type: SUSPICIOUS PERSON(S)
1 EMS Blk: 186605 Fire Blk: 65005 Police Blk:...
2 Location: ADDRESS ,22
3 at NUMBER STREET ,22
4 Entered: 01/01/16 00:00
5 Dispatched: 01/01/16 00:00
6 Enroute: 01/01/16 00:00
7 On Scene: 01/01/16 00:00
8 Transport: / / :
9 Trans Complete: / / :
10 Closed: 01/01/16 00:04
and so on with the reduntant info

Comment: It seems to me that the data layout was not as expected and as such multiple elements got lumped together. That's my guess. You should edit your question to give a better picture of how the data is formatted in the file. As it is now, it's impossible to tell what your file looks like.